# Image does not open when downloaded from URL

Tags: image, c#-4.0, microsoft-teams

Image URI https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/evergreen-assets/stickerassets/teamsquatch-250x250/Teamsquatch_EmailOverload.png 
this image open in browser but when I downloaded it using the following c# code, the downloaded file does not open in image viewer.

Am I missing anything?

```html
public  void DownloadFile(string requestUri, string downloadFilePath, TimeSpan requestTimeout, string token = null)
        {
            using (var webResponse = GetWebResponse(requestUri, requestTimeout, token))
            {
                using (var streamReader = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(downloadFilePath))
                    {
                        streamReader.CopyTo(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static WebResponse GetWebResponse(string requestUri, TimeSpan requestTimeout, string token = null)
        {
            var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            webReq.Method = "GET";
            webReq.Timeout = (int)requestTimeout.TotalMilliseconds;
            webReq.ReadWriteTimeout = (int)requestTimeout.TotalMilliseconds;
            webReq.KeepAlive = true;
            webReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36";
           
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
            return httpResponse;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the response using the online tool http://checkfiletype.com/, it is found that the content we get is gzip so found the solution for it.

We can set decompression on request and then it will automatically decompress and save file in png if we set following:
webReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;